# JS: calling variable from outside of function

Tags: javascript, function, nan

So, i'm inputing variables before function on order to let them grow with each function call.
But when i'm trying to print those or use them in calculations, JS returns either NaN or undefined. When calling from outside of function, everything's ok.
What am i missing?

Upd: Oh, the code!

Upd2: By using various ways to declare var i'm still getting NaN and undefined while testing it with 8+9 output. Used both window.GLD and GLD = 0 instead of var GLD = 0; As far as i got it, i can declare it without var in function and not affect it outside of this one. But how do i drag variable from outside of function?

Upd3: After trying using var GLD=GLD+1 (declaring it inside of function) i am still getting NaN. So the final question: how do i get variable contents into function from outside?

```
    var depth = 0;
    var maxHP = 10;
    var currentHP = 10;
    var DMG = 2;
    var ARM = 1;
    var GLD = 0;
    var currentExp = 0;
    var neededExp = 5;

    var GobHP = 2;
    var GobHPMax = 2;
    var CurrentGobHP=2
    var GobDMG = 1;
    var GobDEF = 0;
    var GobBSInc = 2;
    var GobexpInc = 2;
    var GobDmgDone = 1;

    var dmgDone=0;
    var wpnTier=0;

    var turn=1;

    var nextEvent=0;

    document.getElementById("statusChar").innerHTML="HP: "+currentHP+"/"+maxHP+" DMG: "+DMG+" ARM: "+ARM+" GLD: "+GLD+" EXP: "+currentExp+"/"+neededExp+" Depth: "+depth;
    //It's ok here - code dosent goes NaN or undefined
    function goDeeper()

     {      depth++;
        document.getElementById("statusChar").innerHTML="HP: "+currentHP+"/"+maxHP+" DMG: "+DMG+" ARM: "+ARM+" GLD: "+GLD+" EXP: "+currentExp+"/"+neededExp+" Depth: "+depth;
// and here it dies. Prompt to stop it from going to next step.
            prompt();
```

Comment: Share your code that you've tried.

Comment: In Javascript you got Global and Local variables, Google on these two things. :) Also - http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: By using various ways to declare var i'm still getting NaN and undefined while testing it with 8+9 output. Used both window.GLD and GLD = 0 instead of var GLD = 0; As far as i got it, i can declare it without var in function and not affect it outside of this one. But how do i drag variable from outside of function?

Comment: Can you please isolate problem to a few lines of code, not copypasta of your entire source?

Comment: I'd like to, if i'd knew what's wrong. I've cut it down, though, i hope i didnt missed something important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you provided is almost working: there is no ending } for function goDeeper(). Here is almost unchanged function:

```
function goDeeper()
{      
    depth++;
    document.getElementById("statusChar").innerHTML += "<br>HP: " + currentHP + "/" + maxHP + " DMG: " +DMG + " ARM: " + ARM + " GLD: " + GLD + " EXP: " + currentExp + "/" + neededExp + " Depth: " + depth;
    // prompt();
}
```

I've just changed it to have each output in the new line. And after several calls to goDeeper() the result is:

```
HP: 10/10 DMG: 2 ARM: 1 GLD: 0 EXP: 0/5 Depth: 0
HP: 10/10 DMG: 2 ARM: 1 GLD: 0 EXP: 0/5 Depth: 1
HP: 10/10 DMG: 2 ARM: 1 GLD: 0 EXP: 0/5 Depth: 2
HP: 10/10 DMG: 2 ARM: 1 GLD: 0 EXP: 0/5 Depth: 3
HP: 10/10 DMG: 2 ARM: 1 GLD: 0 EXP: 0/5 Depth: 4
```

So if you still have a problem with undefined/NaN then it should be someting else.

Comment: Hi! Thanks. Looks like this is a right solution, but i've already done it by recreating goDeeper from scratch, also making it easer and getting some code practice. Still i'm thankful :3